# Executable merge.exe (extracted from MSYS2) doesn't run on Windows

Tags: windows, merge, build, msys2, rcs

## 1. Problem explained

I need to run the `merge` tool (part of the GNU RCS project - Revision Control System) on Windows 10. These are the requirements:

- **STEP 1:** The executable `merge.exe` must run in a native Windows cmd terminal.
- **STEP 2:** The `PATH` env variable should not be modified.
- **STEP 3:** The executable can be located in any arbitrary folder (of course, it's okay to put a bunch of dll's next to it if required).

It would lead us too far to explain *why* these requirements are so important. Please, just take them "as-is".

---

## 2. First trial: running the msys executable

I installed MSYS2 in `C:/msys64` and found the executable at this location: `C:/msys64/usr/bin/merge.exe`. So time to try STEP1 ~ STEP3.

**STEP 1**
I can get it to work in a **native Windows terminal** if I add `C:/msys64/usr/bin/` to the `PATH` env variable:

```sh
C:/Users/Kristof>merge.exe a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

huray!

**STEP 2**
Unfortunately, things go wrong when I don't modify the `PATH` env variable and invoke `merge.exe` by its full path instead:

```sh
C:/Users/Kristof>"C:/msys64/usr/bin/merge.exe" a.txt b.txt c.txt
/usr/bin/diff3: subsidiary program 'diff' not found
```

I don't get why this error appears. After all, the executables `diff3.exe` and `diff.exe` are both sitting next to `merge.exe`. Why can't they be found?

**STEP 3**
Well, STEP3 is obviously useless if I can't get the previous step to work first.

---

## 3. Other trials

### 3.1 Purdue binaries

You can find binaries for RCS here:
https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/RCShome/

I downloaded **rcs57pc1.zip** (1.2MB) from that website. Unfortunately, every attempt to run `merge.exe` fails with the following error message:

```sh
diff3.exe: subsidiary program failed
```

I tried the solutions offered on this StackOverflow post, but they won't work either:

[RCS on Windows - rcsmerge always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748493/rcs-on-windows-rcsmerge-always-fails)

### 3.2 ezwinports

I downloaded **rcs-5.7-1.zip** from:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/

When running its `merge.exe` file, I get the following error:

```sh
diff3.exe: Unknown signal 0xEEEEEEEE
merge aborted
```

Indeed, I could not see a `diff3.exe` tool in the unzipped folder. So I copied `diff3.exe` *and* `diff.exe` from my MSYS installation (found at `C:/msys64/usr/bin/`) into the unzipped `rcs-5.7-1` folder. No success. Same error message.

### 3.3 GnuWin32

The GnuWin32 project is known for its many Linux-to-Windows conversions of popular tools. I downloaded GnuWin32 (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) and did a full installation into `C:/gnuwin32/`. I searched through my `C:/gnuwin32/` folder but cannot find a `merge.exe` tool anywhere. This is very weird, because the GNU RCS project is explicitely mentioned as a package from the GnuWin32 project here:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/rcs.htm

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using `diff3.exe` directly instead of `merge.exe`:

[image]

You can put `diff3.exe` in any arbitrary directory, as long as you don't forget to copy these dll's:

- `msys-2.0.dll`
- `msys-iconv-2.dll`
- `msys-intl-8.dll`

This is how to use the executable:

```sh
>diff3 -m myfile.txt ancestor.txt yourfile.txt
```

Unfortunately, it's still needed to add the folder to the `PATH` env variable. However, the actual usage goal was to call the executable from Python, so it can be done this way:

```py
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["PATH"] = "C:/merge/windows/;" + my_env["PATH"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        merge_tool,
        "-m",
        myfile_path,
        ancestor_path,
        yourfile_path,
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    env=my_env,
)

try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    return None
return outs.decode('utf-8').replace('\r\n', '\n')
```